# Python Regex Pattern Issue

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a long string as below and I assign it to var `sentence`.

american diabetes association. standards of medical care in diabetes—2021. diabetes care jan 2021, 44 (supplement 1). post-market performance follow-up post market performance follow up for standardized and established products is covered by other post market surveillance activities as outlined in the post market surveillance plan (according qap 05.15 and sop x_aa_0318). this product has been standardized against the approved ifcc reference method for the measurement of hba1c in human blood and can be transferred to results traceable to dcct/ngsp by calculation. there is more than one commercial test available, and a certified reference method exists

I want to find the index of substring `post-market performance follow-up` and `post market performance follow up` within the `sentence`

I tried 2 methods with Python Regex.

Method 1:

```
pat = 'post-market performance follow-up'

sentence.find(pat)
// result = 118
```

Method 2:

```
pat2 = 'post[\s-]market performance follow[\s-]up'

sentence.find(pat2)
// result = -1 (i.e: not found)
```

I apply the regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/SonFgU/3) and it gives 2 matches. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: FYI, if you test regexes at regex101.com, why not use the [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/SonFgU/3/codegen?language=python)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just find out about regex101.com and do my test. Anyway, I already produce my code and to my surprise, method 2 is not working in my jupyter notebook. Hope you can help.

Comment: You simply must use the Python `re` named capturing group syntax, `<option[^>]+>\[?(?P<VARIABLE>.+?)]?</option>`, i.e. `(?P<VARIABLE>.+?)` (note the `?P`). See https://ideone.com/4bUUws. Please let know if you need more help.